# Cannot send ether to contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I've made the follwoing contract on my private node.

```
> contract
{
  address: "0x27f8df7f80ff48431594ef062ba80b2ad491d27b",
  transactionHash: "0x85303402ad0203f41efbc35abb9188e271ec17755664a9df6ec17b287825a058",
  Execution: function(),
  allEvents: function(),
  capital: function(),
  fixed_rate: function(),
  fixed_side: function(),
  floated_side: function(),
  spread: function()
}
> eth.getBalance("0x27f8df7f80ff48431594ef062ba80b2ad491d27b")
100000000000000000000
> eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[3])
1.39998e+21
```

Then I tried to send ether from a account to contract, then mined.

```
eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[3], to: "0x27f8df7f80ff48431594ef062ba80b2ad491d27b", value: web3.toWei(100,"ether"), gas:1000000})
```

However, it seemed that it cannot send ether. The balance of the contract does not increase. Could you tell me what is the problem?

```
> eth.getBalance("0x27f8df7f80ff48431594ef062ba80b2ad491d27b")
100000000000000000000
> eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[3])
1.39996e+21
```

Comment: is it a private node ? the transaction hash on the regular network does not exist : https://etherscan.io/tx/0x85303402ad0203f41efbc35abb9188e271ec17755664a9df6ec17b287825a058

Comment: Yes, it's private net. I'll add the mention.

Comment: Is your account unlocked? You will get a message "account is locked" when you run `eth.sendTransaction(...)` if you have not unlocked your account.

Comment: It is unlocked. It returns the following code.
`> {bb5f82ead8d56f96ec11f98c826cc926", value: web3.toWei(100, "ether"), gas: 1000000})
I0519 00:11:41.844928   45781 xeth.go:1028] Tx(0x635dce1ebdd3fa8aeccecfe8938a974f0db12c39d26b5821b8ec3edc78b832d2) to: 0x4934f96cbb5f82ead8d56f96ec11f98c826cc926
"0x635dce1ebdd3fa8aeccecfe8938a974f0db12c39d26b5821b8ec3edc78b832d2"`

Comment: are you mining on that node? otherwise the contract wont get mined and included in a block and the transaction wont go through.

Comment: Do transactions to regular addresses work? If so, it sounds like either an out of gas error, or an exception being thrown within the contract, which we can't really help with unless you post the source code.

Comment: Try `miner.start(1)` on the node via `geth attach` and see what happens

Comment: I think you should increase the amount of gas. Probably the transaction doesn't have enough gas to execute.

Comment: Which version of Solidity are you using? From v0.4 onwards you need to add the "payable" keyword in order to send ether to the contract.